# Firefox sluggish after playing an online video or kept open for a long time

Tags: firefox, memory

I am using the 64-bit alternative of Firefox - [Waterfox](http://waterfoxproject.org/). I have been facing this issue even when I was using Firefox. What happens is after I have played at least one video or have kept it open for a long time, the browser and consequently all windows of applications start acting sluggish. By sluggish, I mean the following behavior:

- Laggy animations of tabs / progress bars etc.
- Delay while loading images
- Delay in text fields while moving around the cursor

The only way I am able to restore the smooth behavior is by a restart.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak or an active spawned task not properly closed by the browser.
Did you take a look at the task manger or process list?

Comment: @Irosa: Memory usage of **firefox.exe** is normal. Could you please explain as to how do I trace this leak? Also, why is it affecting other applications?

Comment: There are some shell tools like top; you can probably use some GUI tool to trace memory and CPU usage.
Other tasks can be used to display video or other type of content. If the task hangs or Firefox is not able to terminate it properly, your system could slow down.

Comment: OK, will try that. Also, I have disabled the "plugin-container.exe" in FF. Is that probably causing the problem?